# How to read value from json data and display in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to display name in string format but Main.html page is not reading value from session.json page.so please help me

```js
 var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Session) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.session = Session;
  });

  app.run(function(Session) {}); //bootstrap session;

  app.factory('Session', function($http) {
    var Session = {
      data: {},
      saveSession: function() { /* save session data to db */ },
      updateSession: function() { 
        /* load data from db */
        $http.get('session.json')
          .then(function(r) { return Session.data = r.data;})
      }
    };
    Session.updateSession();
    return Session; 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
   Welcome,
    <pre ng-bind='session.data.username | json'></pre>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```html
This is session.json page but in $http.get('session.json') it is not reading value from this page .

{ "username": "John Smith" }
```

how to read string from the json page to main.html and display

Comment: `document.write` can clear your existing document, at least in some browsers. Don't use it.

Comment: `Session.data = r.data;` `r` seems to be undefined. You probably have errors in console.

Comment: Your code works fine in firefox browser! and then i tried in chrome browser it throws xmlhttprequest error while reading session.json file that means, you are trying to load the session.json as a file protocal chrome doesn't allow this operation (web-security). Anyway my question is are you running your code in any server environment? it should work if you run this code in server environment. By the way you can also try to start your chrome browser like this "chrome.exe --disable-web-security" this will disable the chrome web security and can access file. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See the following code,

```
$http({
            "method": "get",
            "url": "session.json"
        });
```

Here session.json and this file( the file in which this $http call is present) are in the same folder.